# Dropbox iOS SDK authentication issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using Dropbox SDK for iOS, after signing out with
 `[[DBSession sharedSession] unlinkAll];` then sign in with `[[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];` with the same account this message appear.

[image]

Comment: Just a guess, therefore not provided as answer: try to set your DBRestClient instance to nil before calling linkFromController. E.g.: 
        self.restClient = nil;
        [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];

Comment: Hi @marcus I am already set the instance to nil, I don't know whats wrong with this.

Comment: For anyone else seeing this issue, as discussed here https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=114164 please make sure you're using the latest version of the SDK first.